# Regex in R for removing file name from document

Tags: r

I am using tm package and content transformer for modifying the documents in R.
Now I have a document with following text-

"red.c:45:4 error: invalid identifier "

Expected output -

":45:4 error: invalid identifier"

I want to remove the file name from it using regex or any suitable method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try `sub`.  We match zero or more characters that are not a `:` and replace it with `''` (assuming that `:` succeeds the filename)

```
sub('^[^:]*', '', str1)
#[1] ":45:4 error: invalid identifier "
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "red.c:45:4 error: invalid identifier "
```